# 2 select 1 id in 1 query

Tags: sql, oracle

How can i solve the next problem ?

I would like to that in the correct syntax.

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.id OR table2.id = 1;
```

Comment: you need to write like this  -- WHERE table1.id=1 OR table2.id = 1

Comment: Could you explain what you want to get, because even you get one record: 
1. When  id in table 1: Columns from table 1 filled, columns from table 2 nulled.
2. When id in both tables:  Columns from table 1 filled, columns from table 2 filled.
3. When  id in table 2: Columns from table 1 nulled, columns from table 2 filled.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your exact requirement. When you use two tables, first you have to join them and provide necessary filters in `WHERE` clause

Please use below query

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 
WHERE 
table1.id = table2.id 
and table1.id = 1;
```

Comment: you don't need the table2.id = 1 in that query. You are already making an inner join between both of them, so the predicate will be applied afterwards, and as both are already joined by id, you only need to specify table1.id = 1

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like your requirement is kind of a cross join with either table1.id = 1 or table2.id = 2. In that case you would do it like this:

```
select * from table1 cross join table2 where table1.id = 1 or table2.id = 1
```

But pay attention, this being a cross join means you might get a huge number of rows.

A usecase where a cross join makes sense, is when one of the table contains exactly 1 row. That might be a configuration table.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your syntax is wrong. In SQL you need to specify which condition applies to each expression. You cannot combine two fields as part of the same expression. SQL is not a procedural language, it does not provide constructions as arrays or types.

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.id OR table2.id = 1;
```

I guess you are trying to get all records from table1 and table2 where any of the ids is equal to 1. If so, then you need to answer yourself:

- do I want all the columns from both tables ?
- do I want all the records of table1 and table2 where the id = 1 ?

Try to use alias in your queries, it helps to read them. You should rewrite the query as:

```
select a.* , b.* from table1 a , table2 b where a.id = b.id and a.id = 1 ;
```

Although I would remove all fields that are duplicated in both tables, if not Oracle will replace the second iteration of a repeated field with a name follow by _1

Your query also could be rewritten in ANSI SQL

```
select a. , b.* from table1 a inner join table2 b on ( a.id = b.id ) 
where a.id = 1;
```

In your case you will see in the output a column named ID, and a second column named ID_1 ( which is also ID ) but as you did not specify the columns you want to get (you put asterisk), then Oracle needs to qualify the columns in a way that each one is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax would be:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.id AND table1.id = 1;
```

You can also achieve the same result by doing:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.id AND table1.id = 1;
```